# How to not execute INSERT in read-only transaction

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-replication

Postgres server is in hot standbuy mode.
Asynchronou streaming binary replication is used.

Command like

```
INSERT INTO logfile (logdate) values (current_date)
```

Causes error

> cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction.

Maybe it should be changed to

```
INSERT INTO logfile (logdate) 
SELECT current_date
WHERE   ???
```

What where condition should used ? 
It should work starting at Postgres 9.0
If direct where clause is not possible, maybe some plpgsql function can used in where.

Maybe

```
show transaction_read_only
```

result should captured or some function can used.

Alternately application can determine if database is read-only in startup. Should show transaction_read_only   result used for this.

Comment: you cannot run any dml on the instance that is in hot standby mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `INSERT` on a standby server is not possible in pure (non-procedural) SQL because when the server is in standby mode, all the data-modification queries are rejected in planning phase, before it's executed.

It's possible with conditionals in PL/PgSQL.

```
DO $code$
BEGIN
  IF NOT pg_is_in_recovery() THEN
    INSERT INTO logfile (logdate) VALUES (current_date);
  END IF;
END;
$code$;
```

However, it's probably not recommended - it's usually better to test `pg_is_in_recovery()` once (in application code) and then act accordingly.

I'm using `pg_is_in_recovery()` system function instead of `transaction_read_only` GUC because it's not exactly the same thing. But if you prefer that, please use:

```
SELECT current_setting('transaction_read_only')::bool
```

More info: [DO command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html), [conditionals in PL/PgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html), [system information functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-RECOVERY-CONTROL).

Comment: Shold I use `INSERT INTO logfile (logdate) select current_date where not is_in_recovery()  and not  current_setting('transaction_read_only')::bool`  or is it OK to use only one condition?